# Implementing SQLite without C (or any other mainstream languages)

Tags: sqlite, plc

My application is on an embedded PLC platform. The language(s) available are defined by IEC 61131. Trying to hack around my "runtime environment" is not an option. I can manage some low-level file operations, but realtime performance will always be a bottleneck.

I do not need most of what SQLite offers. Basically, I want to define the table structure for my database before hand, in a manner compliant with SQLite. From my PLC, I want to fill the database file with statistical data (large amounts). At some point, these database files will be transferred from their temporary storage on the PLC. There is no need to perform SELECTS or UPDATES. Once the files have been written, the PLC need not touch them again.

But I am not sure I can afford to actually implement an INSERT query, and I know that any database "housekeeping" is out of the question.Can I work with an SQLite database file on a fundamental level, and still expect SQLite to connect to it later without any problems? How easy is it to corrupt the database integrity? What are minimal housekeeping functions that MUST be performed as the file grows larger?

---

PS

- My data is time-dependent and largely VERY linear
- No cross table references/foreign keys
- Standard data types

Comment: Are you looking for something more like a round-robin database? Check out RRDtool. Alternatively I think you ought to just write to a simple intermediate file format and convert it to something more powerful once you get it off the embedded device.

Comment: If you don't need to perform SELECTs and UPDATEs, then you're only inserting the data. In that case, do you actually need a database, rather than just appending data to some .csv file and periodically downloading / rotating it?

Comment: RRDtool is my is my end-game. I am currently using CSV, but I gather many datapoints at a quick rate and my storage quickly becomes bloated. Slicing and dicing my CSV's is painful. Ive basically created my own storage-layer on top of CSV and its starting to get ugly. Things like Enumerations and Timestamps are giving me the most problems.

Comment: A large portion of conversion occurs on my embedded platform. Knowing which CSV files to read, and how to regroup the data is not natural for most existing tools. I would almost rather just take the time to get it right the first time.

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds as if you don't really need a database since you are basically only using the inserts. Instead it may be better(faster) to just store your data in a sequential file in a database friendly format (e.g. csv-file or xml) and then transfer that file when some limit is reached (filesize, time,...).